# "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled. (auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment)

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

I am new to react native and firebase

I had a issue regard to my app which is a cross-platform app(android, ios). I encounter this issue where i just cannot verify user phone number using the firebase phone authentication

**Here is my code:**

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import {
  sharedStyles,
  windowWidth,
  windowHeight,
} from "../../assets/shared/styles.js";
import Signup_email from "./signup_email.js";
import Signup_email_verify from "./signup_email_verify.js";
import Signup_phone from "./signup_phone.js";
import Signup_phone_otp from "./signup_phone_otp.js";
import Signup_password from "./signup_password.js";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../../config/config.js";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification,
  getAuth,
  PhoneAuthProvider,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  auth,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";

const PaginationDot = ({ index, activeIndex }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.dot, index === activeIndex && styles.activeDot]} />
  );
};

export default function Signup_base() {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
  const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
  const [userPhone, setUserPhone] = useState(null);
  const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const auth = getAuth();

  const handleEmailEntered = (email) => {
    setUserEmail(email);
  };

  const handlePhoneEntered = (phone) => {
    setUserPhone(phone);
  };

  const handleEmailValidated = (isValid) => {
    setIsEmailValid(isValid);
  };

  // Generate data array based on the number of slide functions
  const data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => ({
    key: `Slide ${index + 1}`,
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkEmailVerification = async () => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const user = auth.currentUser;

      if (user) {
        await user.reload();

        if (user.emailVerified && activeSlide === 1) {
          // User's email is verified, proceed to the next slide
          setAuthUser(user);
          const nextIndex = (activeSlide + 1) % data.length;
          setActiveSlide(nextIndex);
        }
      }
    };

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      checkEmailVerification();
    }, 1000); // Check every 1 seconds

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Clear interval on component unmount
  }, [activeSlide]);

  const getSlideComponent = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Signup_email
            onEmailEntered={handleEmailEntered}
            onEmailValidated={handleEmailValidated}
          />
        );
      case 1:
        return <Signup_email_verify email={userEmail} />;
      case 2:
        return <Signup_phone onPhoneEntered={handlePhoneEntered} />;
      case 3:
        return <Signup_phone_otp />;
      case 4:
        return <Signup_password />;
      default:
        return <></>;
    }
  };

  const handleSignup_email = async () => {
    if (
      !(
        userEmail === null ||
        userEmail === undefined ||
        userEmail === "" ||
        !isEmailValid
      )
    ) {
      try {
        // Create a user with a temporary password
        const tempPassword = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          userEmail,
          tempPassword
        );

        // Send email verification
        sendEmailVerification(user);

        await auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            setAuthUser(user);
            // Navigate to the next screen or perform any desired action
            const nextIndex = (activeSlide + 1) % data.length;
            setActiveSlide(nextIndex);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
          // Handle case where the email is already in use
          alert(
            "This email address is already registered. Please use a different email."
          );
        } else {
          // Handle other errors
          console.error("Error creating user:", error.message);
        }
      }
    } else if (
      !isEmailValid &&
      !(userEmail === undefined || userEmail === null || userEmail === "")
    ) {
      alert("The entered email format is invalid.");
    } else if (
      userEmail === undefined ||
      userEmail === null ||
      userEmail === ""
    ) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email.");
    }
  };

  const handleSignup_email_verification = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    await user.reload();

    sendEmailVerification(user);
  };

  const newRecaptchaVerifier = () => {
    return new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
      size: "invisible",
      callback: (response) => {
        // Recaptcha callback
      },
    });
  };

  const handleSignup_phone = async () => {
    // const appVerifier = newRecaptchaVerifier();
    // try {
    //   const confirmation = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, userPhone, appVerifier);
    // } catch (error) {
    //   console.error(error);
    // }

    // const result = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
    //   auth,
    //   userPhone,
    //   recaptchaVerifier.current
    // );

    // const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
    // phoneProvider

    //   .verifyPhoneNumber(userPhone, recaptchaVerifier.current)
    //   .then(setVerificationId);
    //   setUserPhone("");

    if (userPhone) {
      try {
        const phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
        const recaptchaVerifier = newRecaptchaVerifier(); // Create a new RecaptchaVerifier
        const verificationId = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
          phoneAuthProvider,
          userPhone,
          recaptchaVerifier
        );

        // Move to the next slide
        const nextIndex = (activeSlide + 1) % data.length;
        setActiveSlide(nextIndex);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending SMS verification code:", error.message);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please enter a valid phone number.");
    }
  };

  // const confirmCode = () => {
  //   const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
  //     verificationId,
  //     code
  //   );
  //   firebase.auth().signInWithCredentials(credential)
  //   .then(() => {
  //     setCode('');
  //   })
  //   .catch((error) => {
  //     alert(error);
  //   })
  //   Alert.alert("")
  // }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        {/* Pagination Dots */}
        <View style={styles.paginationContainer}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            pagingEnabled
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ index }) => (
              <PaginationDot index={index} activeIndex={activeSlide} />
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      {/* Render the appropriate slide component based on the active slide */}
      {getSlideComponent(activeSlide)}

      {/* Additional Signup content */}
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          handleSignup_phone();
          // const nextIndex = (activeSlide + 1) % data.length;
          // setActiveSlide(nextIndex);
          // if (activeSlide === 0) {
          //   handleSignup_email();
          // } else if (activeSlide === 1) {
          //   handleSignup_email_verification();
          // } else if (activeSlide === 2) {
          //   handleSignup_phone();
          // }
        }}
      >
        <LinearGradient
          colors={["#5899E2", "#12B3CA"]}
          style={[sharedStyles.button, { width: windowWidth * 0.8 }]}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
        >
          {activeSlide !== 1 && (
            <Text style={sharedStyles.buttonText}>Next</Text>
          )}
          {activeSlide === 1 && (
            <Text style={sharedStyles.buttonText}>
              Resend Verification Email
            </Text>
          )}
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  paginationContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: windowHeight * 0.02,
  },
  dot: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#BDBDBD", // Inactive dot color
    marginHorizontal: windowWidth * 0.03,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  activeDot: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3", // Active dot color
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});
`
```

I want the user to receive a SMS using the firebase phone auth with 6-digit and user will able to use the number receive to verify thier phone number. This should work for both android and ios.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

please go through below ,modify it accordingly your need and let m know any

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const VerifyPhoneNumber = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');

  const handleSendVerificationCode = () => {
    const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        const verificationId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
        // here store verificationId for later use
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  };

  const handleVerifyCode = () => {
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        //success phone number verified 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //pass error to user 
         console.error(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleSendVerificationCode}>Send Verification Code</button>
      <input type="text" value={verificationCode} onChange={(e) => setVerificationCode(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleVerifyCode}>Verify Code</button>
      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VerifyPhoneNumber;
```

read [environments-js-sdk#polyfills](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk#polyfills)

> Polyfills The Firebase JavaScript SDK is built on the latest
> standards of the web platform. Some older browsers and JavaScript
> environments do not support all the features required by Firebase. If
> you must support these browsers/environments, then you need to load
> polyfills accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Rainy sidewalks, Thanks for the help, but the issue still persists even when I modify accordingly using the code you provided. Btw i am using the expo go for my app. Also i has allow my firebase phone authenticate.  

since my firebase version is "^10.7.2" so instead of import firebase from 'firebase/app' i opt to import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'.

Comment: did you registered your app,add the api key and other configs ?

Comment: Ya i do i has properly modify my firebase config using the config that provided by the firebase. Also i had initialize it as well

Comment: see the ref. in edit and please make your code shorted and readable